# How to use the key of an array to set initial value of dropDownList on Yii1.1

Tags: php, yii

Firstly, I custom the array `arr`, then using the key apple to set the initial value, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php 

   $arr = array('apple'=>'red','banana'=>yellow,'watermelon'=>'green');
   echo $form->dropDownList(
                $model, 
                'color', 
                $arr,
                array(
                        'options'=>array('apple'=>array('selected'=>true))
                ));


?>
```

Comment: Its seems like correct.... please paste your error message.

Comment: you missing single quotes around yellow ..

Comment: l have solved it,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set attrubute before dropDownList

```
$model->color='apple';
```

Or set it in your form (extends CFormModel), e.g.

```
public $color = 'apple';
```